# Facing issue with Safari 5 and Selenium-WebDriver

Tags: selenium, safari, websocket, selenium-webdriver

Gems included by the bundle:

- bundler (1.2.4)
- childprocess (0.3.9)
- ffi (1.4.0)
- json (1.7.7)
- mime-types (1.21)
- multi_json (1.6.1)
- rack (1.5.2)
- rest-client (1.6.7)
- rubyzip (0.9.9)
- selenium-webdriver (2.31.0)
- sinatra (1.3.0 063bcb1)
- sqlite3 (1.3.7)
- sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
- sys-uname (0.9.1)
- testkeeper (0.1.15)
- tilt (1.3.5)
- trollop (2.0)
- useragent (0.4.16)
- websocket (1.0.7)
- xml-simple (1.1.2)

Code/Exception:

```
csut11:current demo$ bundle exec irb
1.9.2-p290 :001 > require "selenium-webdriver"
=> true
1.9.2-p290 :002 > browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :safari
EOFError: end of file reached
from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/server.rb:37:in `read_nonblock'
from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/server.rb:37:in `receive'
from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/bridge.rb:60:in `raw_execute'
from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/bridge.rb:40:in `create_session'
from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/bridge.rb:23:in `initialize'
from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `new'
from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `for'
from /Users/demo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
from (irb):2
from /Users/demo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.2-p290 :003 >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue logged in selenium
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5318

tracking issue for fix
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5322